# RegistryPermission exception using the Client Side Object Model of SharePoint 2013 in a sandboxed CRM 2013 Online Plugin

Tags: authentication, plugins, sandbox, sharepoint-2013, dynamics-crm-2013

I’m trying to connect to SharePoint 2013 Online (using CSOM) from within a sandboxed plugin in CRM 2013 Online . For that to work, I merged the SharePoint Client and Client.Runtime DLL’s with ilmerge.exe into my plugin DLL. But as soon as the following code:

```
_context = new ClientContext(spSiteUrl)
{
    Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securePassword)
};
```

tries to create the `SharepointOnlineCredentials` it throws an exception because of the Sandbox limitations:

```
System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type ‘System.Security.Permissions.RegistryPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089′ failed.
```

Did anyone solve this problem, or are there other options for CSOM authenticating with SharePoint 2013 Online?

Comment: Did you ever solve the issue of connecting to Sharepoint from CRM?

Comment: @sreimer Unfortunately not. I ended up creating an external proxy web service, which handles all SharePoint related business logic. From the plugin I call this web service to do all the work. Keep in mind that the SharePoint performance with larger databases (i.e. > 35 GB) is pretty poor, so you can run into the two minute plugin execution time limit. In that case your plugin will be killed. Another option would be the use the good-old SharePoint web services directly from the plugin instead of using CSOM.

Comment: Office 365 appears to still need authentication tokens for the webservice which is where I'm stuck using REST

Comment: @sreimer Maybe this article by Wictor Wilén can help you with that: [http://www.wictorwilen.se/post/how-to-do-active-authentication-to-office-365-and-sharepoint-online.aspx](http://www.wictorwilen.se/post/how-to-do-active-authentication-to-office-365-and-sharepoint-online.aspx)